# jQuery setting the tr border w/ nested table on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an issue getting the tr to change the border when it has a nested table.  Can someone help me out with this.

Here is my table structure

```
<table class="SearchResults" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tblResultsHTML">
<tbody>
        <tr class="BlackHeader">
    <td>header here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>
                <table class="SearchResults" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
                        <tr class="GroupHeader">
            <td>group 1</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td width="75%">sub 1</td>
                            <td valign="top">sub 2</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
               </table>
           </td>
   </tr>
       <tr>
    <td>
                 <table class="SearchResults" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
                        <tr class="GroupHeader">
            <td>group 2</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td width="75%">sub 1</td>
                            <td valign="top">sub 2</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

my jquery which worked when i didn't have nested tables is this

```
    $('#tblResultsHTML').live("mouseover mouseout", function (event) {
    if (event.type == "mouseover") {
        $(this).contents('td').css({ 'border': '2px solid black', 'border-left': 'none', 'border-right': 'none' });
        $(this).contents('td:first').css('border-left', '2px solid black');
        $(this).contents('td:last').css('border-right', '2px solid black');
    } else {
        $(this).contents('td').css('border', 'none');
    }
});
```

What I want to happen is that the whole row containing the nested table has a border when I hover it.  So if I put the mouse over group 1, the whole nested table in that row will have a border.  Does this make sense??

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the cell to have a border, or the row, or the nested table?

Comment: I want the entire row of the parent table to have a border.  So the entire nested table would have a border.

Comment: Those are not the same thing. Just because the row has one cell, and the cell contains a table, does not mean row = cell = table.

Comment: I am aware, just in the case it does.  At any rate, I would like every row within the parent table to have the border on hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dQgXF/2/

Remove the "SearchResults" class from your outer table and try this JS:

```
$('.SearchResults').live(
    {
        mouseover: function() {
            $(this).parent().css({
                border:'2px solid black',
            });
        },
        mouseout: function() {
            $(this).parent().css({
                border:0,
            });
        },
    });
```

Comment: or change to `$('.SearchResults.SearchResults')`  I tested and that works :)

Comment: I was getting an exception in jquery with the above syntax.  This worked though! Thank you `$('.SearchResults').live("mouseover mouseout", function (event) {
        if (event.type == "mouseover") {
            $(this).parent().css({
                border:'2px solid black',
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().css({
                border:0,
            });
        }
    });`

Comment: Note: take out the extra comma's at the end of things :)

Comment: @Andy: are you using the latest version of jQuery? You need 1.4 or greater to use my approach.

Comment: the selector I used says: find "child of one class in a class", does not matter what the class is "called" :)

Comment: just to add a twist... how would I change the background color or the first tr in the nested table that now has a border around it??

Comment: @Andy: familiarize yourself with http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/ and experiment. At any point while traversing you can find out where you are by using something like `alert($(selector)[0].nodeName)`

Comment: better: $('.SearchResults.SearchResults').live(     {  
  mouseover: function() {  
      $(this).parent().css({ border:'2px solid black'});       
  }, 
  mouseout: function() { 
    $(this).parent().css({border:0}); 
}
});

Comment: With a CSS class definition for .reddy{background-color:red} $('.SearchResults .SearchResults').live( { mouseover: function() { $(this).parent().css({ border:'2px solid black'}); $(this).find('tr').eq(0).addClass('reddy'); }, mouseout: function() { $(this).parent().css({border:0}); $(this).find('tr').eq(0).removeClass('reddy'); } });

Comment: NOTE: I messed up the selector on the first example, a space between them is hard to see :)